# Wordpress custom post type search results page

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I set up a custom search form to search and display results of my custom post type. The form is:

```
<form class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
  <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search&hellip;">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="resource-library">  
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

In my search.php I want to direct folks to a custom search php file called search-resource-library.php if the content type is resource-library. So I put this at the top of my search.php page:

```
<?php
// store the post type from the URL string
$post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
// check to see if there was a post type in the
// URL string and if a results template for that
// post type actually exists
if ( isset( $post_type ) && locate_template( 'search-' . $post_type . '.php' ) ) {
  // if so, load that template
  get_template_part( 'search', $post_type );

  // and then exit out
  exit;
}
?>
```

I get exactly what this is doing but I can't seem to store the post type from the URL string supposedly set in the search form html.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "store" the post type? Do you mean that this line: `$post_type = $_GET['post_type']` is not setting the post type? Or something else?

Comment: correct. I'm not able to append the post_type to the url after clicking the submit button in the search form. I need it to pass a ?post_type=research-library in the url.

Comment: Sorry, that's more confusing.  Does `$post_type` get the right value in your code above, or not? If not, did you try `$post_type = $_POST['post_type'];`

Comment: No it doesn't. $post_type = $_GET['post_type']; is supposed to look for the value of "post_type" in the url string set by the hidden input in the form code: <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="resource-library">. I'm probably going about this wrong fundamentally.

Comment: To clarify further this works: $post_type = 'research-library';
But the problem is that all search queries will then use the custom search php file that I have generated not just the research-library. I need to be able to pass a url parameter "?post_type=research-library" from the search form to the url after clicking submit on the search form. Currently I'm not able to do that.

Comment: Also if anyone knows a better way to get this done I'm def open to suggestion.

Comment: I think I'm ready to post an answer, but would appreciate it if you could help with the one question I asked earlier: What happens if you try `$post_type = $_POST['post_type']` ?

Comment: I get the same result when $_POST['post_type'] as when using $_GET['post_type']. It seems like wordpress is removing url parameters completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. My original code and method is correct. The url parameters were not being passed from the search form because a plugin called "Nice Search" was installed. This plugin redirects ?s=query searches to /search/query, and converts %20 to +.