# Custom, separate search form and search results page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, search

**Goal/Information**

I'm trying to set up a custom search field and custom search results page to display one category of pages. I need these results on a separate, custom search results page so I can customize how the results are displayed without affecting the default search.

For context, I'm setting up a gallery where the user can search for keywords and relevant pages will be displayed as a thumbnail grid, with each thumbnail linking to a page containing more information on the image.

Each page, containing the image and information, is set up as a page (not post) under the category `images`.

I'm not sure this is relevant, but in a previous project I've set the default search to exclude `images` pages with the following code in my functions.php (category ID is 30). I've tried removing this code and it didn't affect my problem described below.

```
/* Exclude a Category from Search Results */
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'search_exc_cats' );
function search_exc_cats( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_admin )
        return $query;
    if( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in' , array( 30 ) ); // Cat ID
    }
    return $query;
}
```

**What I've Tried**

I'm still learning php and have spent many hours on this to no avail. Most recently I tried tweaking some code from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145303/wordpress-custom-post-type-search-results-page).

My resultant custom search form looks like this:

```
<form class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get">
  <input name="s" type="text" placeholder="Search Images" />
  <input name="post_type" type="hidden" value="page" />
  <input name="category_name" type="hidden" value="images" />
  <input alt="Search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I've added the following code to the top of my search.php to attempt to redirect to another results page, in this case search-page.php, if the post type has been specified:

```
<?php
// store the post type from the URL string
$post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
// check to see if there was a post type in the
// URL string and if a results template for that
// post type actually exists
if ( isset( $post_type ) && locate_template( 'search-' . $post_type . '.php' ) ) {
    // if so, load that template
    get_template_part( 'search', $post_type );

    // and then exit out
    exit;
}
?>
```

*Note: I took this directly from the similar question linked above.*

I've duplicated search.php into search-page.php, removing the code above from the latter.

**Problem**

Now let's do a search in the custom form above for "marble" (a term featured in one of the `image` pages). The URL looks right (`http://example.com/%3C?s=marble&post_type=page&category_name=images`), but I get a 404. In addition, normal searches (those not in the custom form) now take me to a white page – not even a 404. When I remove the above code from functions.php, the default search works properly. (Custom search still 404s.)

**Other Attempts**

I've also read this guide from Smashing Magazine a few times – [Building An Advanced WordPress Search With WP_Query](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/advanced-wordpress-search-with-wp_query/) – but can't quite pick out the information relevant to me.

I've tried a couple dozen other guides and questions, but most of them deal with searching for a specific post type alone (and not a category) or searching from a radio-button selection of categories. I haven't been able to scrape any working solutions from them.

Are there any tweaks to what I've tried – or completely different solutions altogether – that will help achieve the desired effect? Specifically, **how to create a custom search form for one type of page category, leading to a customizable, separate search results page (independent from the default search results page).**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Second note: in the `http://example.com/%3C?s=marble&post_type=page&category_name=images` the `%3C` bit doesn't look right, does it?

Comment: Yep, you're right on the first one. Somewhere in my copy-paste process that character messed up. As for the second note, I noticed that too. Not sure why it happens. Though when I manually enter `http://example.com/?s=marble&post_type=page&category_name‌​=images` (without the `%3C` bit) I still get the same result.